# How can I change my form so that only selected fields are posted

Tags: php, post

I have a form automatically generated from a mysql query with all the books available to be ordered for our bookstore. The problem is that ISBNs for all books available are posted instead of only the ones that we've selected, and that wastes a lot of memory.

Is it possible to only post the data that we've selected or does every input field within the  brackets have to be posted?

Here's what the form looks like:

```
<form name="form" action="postdata.php" method="post">
<?php
$k=0;    
while ($books = mysqli_fetch_array($booksq)){
   $bookISBN[$k]=$books['theISBN'];
   echo '<textarea name="'.$bookISBN[$k].'"></textarea>'.$bookISBN[$k].'<br>;
   $k+=1;
   }
?>
</form>
```

Using that form we select which books we want to order and enter the quantity we want in the text area.

Here's what the $_POST data looks like with a few books selected:

```
  [9780872865082]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9780872865198]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [9780872865709]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9780872866294]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [9780912678764]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9780930324872]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [9780941920056]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9780971084636]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9780975571644]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9781553800439]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9781556591075]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9781566892759]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9781570270871]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9781617753121]=>
  string(0) ""
```

How do I change my form so data only posts when string(1) "1"?

Comment: wouldn't checkboxes be better for that task? the value can only be 0 or 1?

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem, but you should do `<textarea name="<?= $bookISBN ?>"><?= $count ?></textarea>` instead of echoing the whole element.

Comment: Can't use checkboxes-- sometimes we order more than one copy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
while ($books = mysqli_fetch_array($booksq)){
    $bookISBN[$k]=$books['theISBN'];
    if ($Count == 1) {
        echo '<textarea name="'.$bookISBN[$k].'">'.$Count.'</textarea> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to be able to see all of the books and have the option of ordering any of them on the form, so that won't work.

Comment: You can use something another tags. I mean if $Count = 0 you can put this item not in <textarea> but you can put this to <p> or something that don't send. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Sorry, the $Count variable isn't relevant to this question-- I took it out to try and make my question clearer. That only shows up after we've saved the order once and come back to edit it-- but we need to be able to see all the books possible and change the quantity in the text area from zero to one or more when we do orders.

Comment: I think it's impossible. I mean if you make some fields that are empty and if these fields are important to show. Because form sends all data in it. Only if you can somehow change data before send

Comment: maybe I could use javascript to generate an array and submit that instead?

Comment: You can create something like form, but not form and button. When someone click to button your js code get parameters from "form" and after some algorithm send data to php file via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to use javascript to separate the ISBNs that we want to order into one field that can then be posted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatesum() {
      var m=0, ISBN, order, list=[], count=<?php echo $k; ?>-1, quant;
          while (m <= count) {
            tmp = 'n'+m;
            quant = (Number(document.getElementById(tmp).value));
            ISBN = (Number(document.getElementById(tmp).name));
            order = quant+'.'+ISBN;
            if (quant>0) {list.push(order);}
            m++;
          }

      document.getElementById('list').value = list;
    }    

</script>
```